# zabbix check via script always triggers

Tags: zabbix

I have a script on a server, that either outputs "OK - foobar buz foo", or "ERROR - blah blah foo". In the latter case I would like to have an alarm triggered in zabbix.

What I have done so far:

I have configured the UserParameter in zabbix as follows:

```
# cat /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_check_reposync.conf
UserParameter=spacewalk.reposync[*],/usr/local/sbin/check_reposync.py $1
```

I reloaded the zabbix agent, and the following check works as expected:

```
# zabbix_agentd -t spacewalk.reposync[centos7-x86_64.log]
spacewalk.reposync[centos7-x86_64.log]        [t|OK: All good for the repository "centos7-x86_64"]
```

Now I have created an item in the zabbix 3.2 web interface, which is of type "character", and defined a trigger, as

```
{somehost.acme.org:spacewalk.reposync[centos7-x86_64.log].str("ERROR")}=1
```

My understanding is that since the zabbix_agentd does not return the string "ERROR", this trigger should not fire. However I have an alarm for this trigger.

What did I configure wrong? Failing that, how can I debug this?

**SOLUTION:**

After I was made aware of ways to debug and the most likely cause - a permission problem - I changed the configuration as follows:

To make sure zabbix is not hampered by permissions, I have the check run as root via sudo:

```
# cat /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_check_reposync.conf
UserParameter=spacewalk.reposync[*],sudo /usr/local/sbin/check_reposync.py $1
```

And then added the needed sudo config in `/etc/sudoers.d/10_zabbix`:

```
zabbix ALL=(root)  NOPASSWD:/usr/local/sbin/check_reposync.py *
```

The alternative would be to provision acls allowing the check. This is probably better from a security point of view. However from an ops perspective the sudo approach seemed simpler and easier to debug and rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `-t` or `-p` to test items. The way you ran it, it is executed with the permissions of the `root` user. Even if you were to run it as the Zabbix user, environment and other factors would differ. Use `zabbix_get` to test against a running agent instead. http://www.zabbixbook.com/2017/08/22/debugging-zabbix-userparameters/ goes in more detail.

In this case, it is most likely a permission error.

Comment: Actually, there is a permission problem, thank you for pointing this out. I need to figure out the correct acls. Once I have verified that I will accept your answer. I would give you another plus 1 for that zabbixbook link :)